# sass file can be viewed in web developer tool but when open in browser get 404 error

Tags: css, browser, sass

sass file can be viewed in web developer tool (style editor) of browser. But if tried to open in new tab of browser get 404 error.

e.g.

website :-  https://getbootstrap.com/

scss url :- https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/scss/bootstrap.scss

Can anyone tell me why browser's developer tool can show the contents of scss file but we can't open or download that scss file using url.

Answer (score 2):

You can't see the `.scss` file because the browser doesn't understand how to display it. `.scss` is a different thing than `.css` (which a browser does understand). In order for the browser to know what SCSS is, you need some kind of compiler to output CSS. If you want to get into scss development you should check out a compiler like webpack

https://webpack.js.org/loaders/sass-loader/

or if you just want to check out how its done have a look at codepen & test out some features:)

https://blog.codepen.io/documentation/using-css-preprocessors/

Comment: then powershell or notepad++ or by any other should be able to open it. Why do they all gives 404 (not found) error?